# Sorting an array of strings with respect to an array of integers

Tags: c#, sorting

am a beginner in coding and still learning, i have two arrays , first one for cars and second one for the cars speeds

```
string[] cars = {"Volvo", "BMW","Ford", "Mazda"};

Int[] speeds = {150,130,200,110}
```

So that the speed of volvo is 150 , speed of bmw is 130 speed of ford is 300 ..etc

Is there a method in c# to rearrange the arrays with respect to speed from highest to lowest speed so that the arrays become as follows

```
String[] cars = {"ford","volvo","bmw","mazda"};

Int[] speeds = {300,150,130,110};
```

Comment: So, not merging at all, then, just sorting the array of strings according to the values in the array of ints?

Comment: Sorry , i changed the title it was a mistake , just sorting the array of strings according to the values in the array of integers yeah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concise way to do this is to "zip" the two arrays together into one array of tuples, sort the tuples by speed, and then split the tuples back into two arrays:

```
var tuples = cars.Zip(speeds, (car, speed) => (car, speed))
    .OrderByDescending(tuple => tuple.speed)
    .ToList();
string[] sortedCars = tuples.Select(tuple => tuple.car).ToArray();
int[] sortedSpeeds = tuples.Select(tuple => tuple.speed).ToArray();
```

By adding more calls to Zip, you can sort three or more arrays:

```
var tuples = cars.Zip(speeds, (car, speed) => (car, speed))
    .Zip(colors, (tuple, color) => (tuple.car, tuple.speed, color))
    // .Zip(weights, (tuple, weight) => (tuple.car, tuple.speed, tuple.color, weight))
    .OrderByDescending(tuple => tuple.speed)
    .ToList();
string[] sortedCars = tuples.Select(tuple => tuple.car).ToArray();
int[] sortedSpeeds = tuples.Select(tuple => tuple.speed).ToArray();
string[] sortedColors = tuples.Select(tuple => tuple.color).ToArray();
// int[] sortedWeights = tuples.Select(tuple => tuple.weight).ToArray();
```

But at this point, as Guru Stron noted, you should really consider introducing a Car class instead of working with separate arrays.

Comment: Hi michael i get this error , tuple does not contain a definition for select

Comment: Make sure you have `using System.Linq;` at the beginning of your file.

Comment: Yes , iam usong system.linq but the problem is there

Comment: My code is calling `.Select` on `tuples` (plural), which is a List of tuples. Make sure you're not calling `.Select` on a single `tuple`.

Comment: Well, you are a genious sir !

Comment: Can i use same way for 3 arrays , cars,speeds,colors ???

Comment: Yes ,thanks alot , am really in the process of making a mechanics for a simple game so i just wanted to build the code with the way i can , then ill try to enhance the code with the more experience i get , ill try to have a look at the OOP sonce its suggested to me more than once

Comment: @goldrecoverysayf I would say this is the point to definitely introduce a class. Updated my answer to incorporate that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use framework provided [`Array.Sort<TKey,TValue>(TKey[], TValue[], IComparer<TKey>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-7.0#system-array-sort-2(-0()-1()-system-collections-generic-icomparer((-0)))) with comparer (for reverse sorting):

> Sorts a pair of `Array` objects (one contains the keys and the other contains the corresponding items) based on the keys in the first `Array` using the specified `IComparer<T>` generic interface.

```cs
Array.Sort(speeds, cars, Comparer<int>.Create((left, right) => right.CompareTo(left)));
```

This will perform sorting in place, i.e. `speeds` and `cars` will have order of elements changed.

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSAsA3OungJwAUARIDwbgIPtUCUxGSmA2gLrYDGAhmADO2ALzYA3lQBqAewA2ANxlUANNioAhALIB1VVQBiMsABNV6rXwBeJvlQC+LdAEsowLtkEAHAKY+TwmLi2EgArJhqSADMEdgImLFIbNiO6ACCYGB8AJ4AdADKxsAU3n4BavxCagDCMgC2XgI+YAA8rsAAfLnVYD58wD4UFHI+AGbAamDOAOYAFsCMoh3YU3PA3fWNvQAqMsNjC4zMJGijxhTt2M6i2JiEV9gtvAKCuQAyPlDTwLP3zgDU/0Y6HE6Gw4NwSEoABIqOJKoJ2M5OPZsABaCSlfyI5H2JgsexAA)

Note that usually you would not want to store data just as arrays, object-oriented approach (which is arguably the prevalent paradigm in C#) would be to create a class which will have property for speed and name and fill them accordingly, and then sort the collection of cars.

**UPD**

Example of working with class:

```cs
var cars = new Car[]
{
    new() {Name = "Volvo", Speed = 150, Color = "White"},
    new() {Name = "BMW", Speed = 130, Color = "Blue"},
    new() {Name = "Ford", Speed = 200, Color = "Green"},
    new() {Name = "Mazda", Speed = 110, Color = "Black"},
};

var sortedCars = cars
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.Speed)
    .ToList();

foreach(var car in sortedCars)
{
   Console.WriteLine(car);   
}

public class Car
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public int Speed {get; set;}
     public string Color {get; set;} // possibly use enum here
    
    public override string ToString() 
        => $"Name: {Name}, Speed: {Speed}, Color: {Color}";
}
```

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=)

Comment: this is enabling bad behavoir, and doesn't address the root cause of why you'd ever want something like this

Comment: Hi guru, thanks for your reply , what would be the problem or disadvantages if i store the data in arrays instead of using OOP ??

Comment: @goldrecoverysayf usually in C# you want to model your data using OO paradigm, it simplifies working with it, i.e. if you had just a single array of `Car` class here you would need to sort only it instead of maintaining order in two "unrelated" ones (or modifying data, for example if you will want to change price of BMW). Though there can be cases when you will want to store data as arrays they are quite rare actually and you would have much easier time creating corresponding types to represent your domain model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tuples. You can make an array of a tuple like this:

```cs
(string Name, int Speed)[] cars = {("ford", 300), ("volvo", 150)};
```

When you want to access e.g. the second car in the array you can do:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + cars[1].Name + " Speed: " + cars[1].Speed);
```

Sort it like this:

```cs
cars.OrderBy(x => x.Speed);
```